# How to use param Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, parameters, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can't set about, interest and relationship on param string using Facebook API.

api code:

```
 {
  "about": "I am simple man",
  "relationship_status": "Single",
  "interested_in": [
    "male"
  ],
  "id": "103249693763348"
}
```

my param code:

```
params.about = JSON.stringify([{
        "about": I am simple man,
        "privacy": '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
        "ref": "nux_android"
    }]);
params.relationship_status = JSON.stringify([{
        "relationship_status": single,
        "privacy": '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
        "ref": "nux_android"
    }]);
params.interested_in = JSON.stringify([{
        "interested_in": male,
        "privacy": '{"value":"EVERYONE"}',
        "ref": "nux_android"
    }]);
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? do you want du UPDATE those values? that´s not possible, as you can see in the api reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user#Updating

Comment: also, of course you can´t just set their privacy status with an app. that would be weird. and what would the use case for this be?